# Añadir una columna a la zona de Tasks de Pulse en Magnolia

Tags: java

Buenos días, estoy empezando en Magnolia y no encuentro información en la documentación de Magnolia o en sus foros sobre como añadir más columnas o columnas personalizadas a la zona del Pulse o inbox donde se visualizan las Tareas o Tasks.

La única a información que he encontrado es [Add custom column to Inbox](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/WIKI/Add+custom+column+to+Inbox), pero la información esta anticuada y las clases inbox que utiliza desparecen en versiones más actualizadas de Magnolia.

¿Podrían indicarme como añadir más columnas al Pulse o enviar un vinculo a donde pudiera encontrarse dicha información?.

Gracias por las molestias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final encontre una forma de hacerlo creando un módulo que sobreescribiese la forma del Task Inbox añadiendo un par de columnas extras y rellenandolas con la información que necesitaba, de todos modos este procedimiento solo se puede hacer a partir de la versión 5.14 en adelante que es cuando se puede acceder a las clases de Magnolia que crean este componente a través de la configuración en Magnolia, en versiones anteriores la llamada a dicha clase es interna y no puede modificarse facilmente la llamada a la clase de creación del Task Inbox.

Comment: ok. ¿Y por qué no compartís el código de ese módulo así tu respuesta le puede servir a otro con tu mismo problema?